# Running Source Connector on Demand and Not Based on poll.interval.ms

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

1. I have a table that is updated once / twice a day, but I want the data to be pushed to Kafka immediately after the table is updated.  Is it possible to avoid running the connector every poll.interval.ms, but rather to run it only after the table is updated (sync on demand or trigger the sync in some other way after the table update)
2. I apologize if this question is stupid... Can sink connector be running on one Kafka cluster, but pull messages from another Kafka cluster and insert them into Postgres.  I'm not talking about replicating messages from Cluster A to Cluster B and then inserting messages from Cluster B to Postgres.  I'm talking about Connector running on Cluster B but pulling messages from Cluster A and writing them to Postgres.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you use log-based change data capture (Debezium, etc) then you capture changes as soon as they are there, without needing to re-query the database. If you use query-based CDC then you do have to query the database on a polling interval. For query-based vs log-based CDC see this [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc) or [talk](https://rmoff.dev/no-more-silos).

   One option would be to use the Kafka Connect REST API to control the connector - but you're kind of going against the streaming paradigm here and will start to find awkward edges in doing this. For example, when do you decide to pause the connector? How do you determine that it's ingested all the changes? etc.

   Using log-based CDC is low-impact on the source system and commonly the route that people go.
2. Kafka Connect does not run on your Kafka cluster. Kafka Connect runs as its own cluster. Physically, it can be co-located for purposes of dev/sandbox environment (this [ref arch](https://www.confluent.io/resources/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/) is useful for production). See also this talk "[Running Kafka Connect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dXXfkoXXBbs&t=1191s)".

   So in your example, "Cluster B" is actually a Kafka Connect cluster - and it would be configured to read from Kafka cluster "A", and that is fine.